# Issues running tensorflow-quantum on colab

Tags: tensorflow-quantum

I am tying to run TF Quantum hello world code on colab (hello_many_worlds.ipynb) available at the following, but having issues running it.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/quantum/blob/master/docs/tutorials/hello_many_worlds.ipynb#scrollTo=saFHsRDpkvkH

1. The first cell itself didn't run
   !pip install tensorflow==2.7.0

I googled and found 2.8.0 is latest and tried
!pip install tensorflow==2.8.0rc0 which worked ok.

2. !pip install tensorflow-quantum==0.7.2
   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-quantum==0.7.2 (from versions: none)
   ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-quantum==0.7.2

I was expecting hello world code to be in working state but it doesn't appear to be working.
Any ideas? Is there a working TF-quantum code to experiment with?

Thanks!